# read returns true regardless of variable content

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following code snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    ls "$1"
    exitstatus=$?
    if [[ $exitstatus != 0 ]]; then
        read -n 1 -p "Retry? (y/n)" ch
                    echo
        if [[ ! $ch =~ [Yy] ]]; then
            break
        fi
    fi
    exit $exitstatus
done
```

Executing this script shows that the `[[ ! $ch =~ [Yy] ]]` is executed regardless of the contents of `$ch`.

```
$ ./test.sh /foo
ls: cannot access /foo: No such file or directory
Retry? (y/n)y
$ ./test.sh /foo
ls: cannot access /foo: No such file or directory
Retry? (y/n)n
$
```

I tried commenting out things, and this seems to show the expected behaviour:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    #ls "$1"
    #exitstatus=$?
    #if [[ $exitstatus != 0 ]]; then
        read -n 1 -p "Retry? (y/n)" ch
        if [[ ! $ch =~ [Yy] ]]; then
            break
        fi
    #fi
    #exit $exitstatus
done
```

Executing above in the shell gives:

```
$ ./test.sh
Retry? (y/n)y
Retry? (y/n)y
Retry? (y/n)n
$
```

What am I doing wrong in the first case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exit $exitstatus` exits the loop after the first try. It should be outside the loop.

Comment: Could also change the `if` statement which tests `$exitstatus` to be another `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have several logic problems:

(1) You asked for retry, but if the answer was y, you never read in a new filename to test against, so it would always fail.

(2) also glaring was when you asked for a retry, you then did this: You got a Y on retry, but then just dumped the user into `break` and you went nowhere further :)

```
read -n 1 -p "Retry? (y/n)" ch
    echo
    if [[ ! $ch =~ [Yy] ]]; then  ## testing for y, then we will retry right! - NOPE, just break :(
        break
```

(3) those nasty while true loops. Think about what your loop should break on and use that test, not some loop forever and hope to break at the right spot. Nevertheless, turning a couple of bits of logic around you can make it work like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## initialize variables
ch=y
srchfile="$1"

## while loop test for Y or y
while [[ $ch == [Yy] ]]; do

    # attempt listing on srchfile
    ls "$srchfile"
    exitstatus=$?

    # if bad exit status, prompt to retry?
    if [[ $exitstatus != 0 ]]; then
        read -n 1 -p "Retry? (y/n)" ch
        echo
        # test for y or Y answer
        if [[ $ch == [^Yy] ]]; then
            break
        fi

        # if retry, read new filename to test
        read -p "Enter a new name for $srchfile : " srchfile
    else
        # that pesky file has been found, let's do something with it!
        printf "You have successfully found file : %srchfile\n"
        printf "(now do something useful with with it)\n"

        break

    fi
done

exit $exitstatus
```